PyTube not downloading correct quality audio file
When I first wrote this code it worked fine and would download me the 160kbps OPUS WEBM file for the URL selected but now for some reason will only download lower a quality than asked for and I can't work out why.
My code is;
from pytube import YouTube 
from sys import argv

link = argv[1]
yt = YouTube(link)

print("Title: ", yt.title)

print("Ciew:", yt.views)

print(yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True))

video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).last()

print(video)

video.download(r'E:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\YTDTEST')

print("DONE")

and the terminal output is
PS E:\Users\XXX\Desktop\PyTube> python pydl2.py "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaJcBJQi7bY"
Title:  Prince & The Revolution - Purple Rain (Official Video), HD (Digitally Remastered and Upscaled)
Ciew: 56547
[<Stream: itag="139" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="48kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.5" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="140" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="128kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="250" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">, <Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">]
<Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
DONE

for some reason it just downloads a 64kbps version of the audio even though as we see from the output I believe have used the right code so can't work out whats gone wrong.

maybe you should some code (if/else) which checks video parameters and use video/audio with the best parameter. Maybe YouTube could change something on web page and maybe the best doesn't have to be .last()

I run code and I get .web which has Audio: opus, 48000 Hz (I checked it using program ffprobe from package ffmpeg) code shows abr="160kbps"  but it can be average bitrate. video.abr shows 160kbps but video.bitrate shows 139578

With your code you should get the opus 160kbps. If not, you can try to get always the audio with more bitrate.
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaJcBJQi7bY')
yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).order_by('bitrate').desc().first().download()

